# Trying to populate second dropdown menu from first dropdown menu php mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am trying to populate 3 menus, 1st menu is created from mysql query and php and displays TVshows ( ie. Modern Family, Dexter, etc ), what I would like to do is once the TVShow is selected populate the next drop down with a new mysql query for seasons ( 1 ,2 ,3 etc.) , then populate a 3rd drop down via mysql query based off the first 2 options being selected for episode

The table is as follows 
| id | Title  | Season | Episode | Extension | URL

I can get the first drop down to display with the following code

```
<?php
$sql="Select distinct title from TVShows";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='TVShow'><option value=''>Select TV Show</option>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo    "<option value=$row[title]>$row[title]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

I have tried many examples but none seem to work right, I would like to be able to do this on the same page as opposed to having the user click submit to go to another page to select the second drop down.

I would like code to dynamically setup the 2nd dropdown based on the first choice, then dynamically setup the 3rd dropdown based on the 1st and second dropdowns

Comment: what your tables look like?  maybe you can get all data in one query and just do the one loop

Comment: TVShow table is as follows
| id | Title  | Season | Episode | Extension | URL

Comment: you're looking for a cascading dropdown using ajax, check this tutorial: http://buffernow.com/cascading-dropdown-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` does not fetch an associative array.

Try using `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead

Comment: Looking for code to create 2nd and 3rd dropdowns dynamically based on previous dropdown selection, I will look into fetch_assoc though

Answer (score 0):

For better performance on the user end you might consider loading all results from the db (and then ideally caching them) and then hiding and showing the appropriate ones with javascript.

This way if users are clicking on your menu a lot you're not making a ton of unnecessary round trips to the db.